# CASE, WHEN and THEN keeps returning only 0 or 1, not string

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

My stored procedure returned data to be used in the quote. There is an optional minimum charge. A user can set a minimum charge. However, for that minimum charge to be applied, user needs to check a box saying **Apply Minimum Charge**. I've then 3 cases I'd like to track.

1. If the minimum charge is set, the check box is checked, the minimum charge is superior to the total, which means that the minimum charges has been applied. In that case, return 1.
2. If the minimum is superior to the total, but the checkbox is not checked, which means that the minimum charge was not applied even though the min charge is sup to the total. In that case, returns 2.
3. Otherwise, returns 0.

Here's the part of my stored procedure responsible of that logic.

```
,CASE
    WHEN (ISNULL(PT.TranslationMasterTaskID, 0) > 0) 
         AND PTM.UseMinClientCharge = 1  
         AND (PTM.MinClientCharge > COALESCE(PT.RoundedClientTotal,0))
         THEN 1
    WHEN (ISNULL(PT.TranslationMasterTaskID, 0) > 0) 
         AND PTM.UseMinClientCharge = 0  
         AND (PTM.MinClientCharge > COALESCE(PT.RoundedClientTotal,0))
         THEN 2
    ELSE 0  
  END AS MinClientChargeWarning
```

I don't understand why is not showing 2 as result. Even when I'm sure it should. I've tried to change 1, 2, and 3 to '1', '2', and '3', but I'm still getting either **1** or **0**.

Is there any reason, I'm getting only **0** or **1**?

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Given that no one on StackOverflow can see your data it's impossible for anyone here to check, but one reason would be that the data you're using doesn't satisfy the criteria for the second `WHEN` clause. Best of luck.

Comment: Someone wrote an answer then erase it. It was about the type of column. I've checked, it was BIT that was there before I modified the logic but I forgot to change it.

Comment: Have you tried to run a query from your tables with criteria that match case 2?  Are there rows?

Comment: @MauriceReeves, you are right. As I can't paste the whole sproc here, I've cut a chunk of the stored procedure that I can run independently while also querying the table to match the variation when in both places.

Comment: So there are rows?  Have you inserted the result set into a temp table to look at the results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So run the following sample query.  You'll notice that all three values get returned.  Change UseMinClientCharge  to BIT, and you'll notice that only two get returned.

The reason is that BIT implicitly converts any value other than 0 (false) to 1 (true).

We can certainly tweak other values to force the default case, but I suspect this is what you're referring to.

```
 -- Begin Sample Data

CREATE TABLE #PT (
RowID INT NOT NULL,
TranslationMasterTaskID INT NULL,
RoundedClientTotal INT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE #PTM (
RowID INT NOT NULL,
UseMinClientCharge  INT NULL,
MinClientCharge  INT NULL
)


INSERT INTO #PT
        ( RowID, TranslationMasterTaskID,RoundedClientTotal )
VALUES  ( 1,1,1 )
INSERT INTO #PT
        ( RowID, TranslationMasterTaskID,RoundedClientTotal )
VALUES  ( 2,1,1 )
INSERT INTO #PT
        ( RowID, TranslationMasterTaskID,RoundedClientTotal )
VALUES  ( 3,1,1 )


INSERT INTO #PTM
        ( RowID, UseMinClientCharge,MinClientCharge )
VALUES  ( 1,0,2 )
INSERT INTO #PTM
        ( RowID, UseMinClientCharge,MinClientCharge )
VALUES  ( 2,1,2 )
INSERT INTO #PTM
        ( RowID, UseMinClientCharge,MinClientCharge )
VALUES  ( 3,2,2 )

-- End Sample Data


SELECT CASE
    WHEN (ISNULL(PT.TranslationMasterTaskID, 0) > 0) 
         AND PTM.UseMinClientCharge = 1  
         AND (PTM.MinClientCharge > COALESCE(PT.RoundedClientTotal,0))
         THEN 1
    WHEN (ISNULL(PT.TranslationMasterTaskID, 0) > 0) 
         AND PTM.UseMinClientCharge = 0  
         AND (PTM.MinClientCharge > COALESCE(PT.RoundedClientTotal,0))
         THEN 2
    ELSE 0  
  END AS MinClientChargeWarning 
FROM #PT PT 
JOIN #PTM PTM ON (PTM.RowID = PT.RowID)


DROP TABLE #PT
DROP TABLE #PTM
```